# How to coalesce two column with default value 0 in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I have a case when select data from PostgreSQL the table have more than 3 columns; 2 columns are a numeric type with a default value of 0 for both of them.  While inserting data into Column A, it is filled with some numeric value.
So now I wanna select with the COALESCE function such that if Column B is still 0, it will return the value from Column A.

How can I do that?

Comment: The COALESCE function is the standard SQL way of processing NULL values.  Zeros are not NULL; it is not remotely clear that using COALESCE is appropriate for this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1: use `nullif`

```
coalesce(nullif("B", 0), "A")
```

Option 2: use `CASE`

```
CASE WHEN "B" = 0 THEN "A" ELSE "B" END
```

I'd go for option 2, even though it doesn't use `coalesce` as you requested.